# Custom input component как правильно настроить валидацию?

Tags: angular, input, валидация

Здравствуйте я совсем новичек и трудно поддается понимание логики, прошу подсказать как настроить валидацию, есть Custom-input component(переиспользуемый компонент) он используется в sign-in conponent при загрузке страницы инпуты сразу становятся не валидными, ожидаю что бы инпут был серым и начал реагировать только после того когда его заполняешь.
[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-6x1eh2?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcustom-input%2Fcustom-input.component.html)

`Custom-input`
css

```
.input {
  display: block;
  border:1px solid #c8cace;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: #000000;
  padding: .5rem 1rem;
  background: #FFF;
  width: 50%;
}
:host.ng-invalid.ng-touched .input {
  border-color: #c61e1e;
  margin: 0;
}

:host.ng-invalid.ng-touched .input:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(198, 30, 35, 0.5);
  margin: 0;
}

:host.ng-valid.ng-touched .input {
  border-color: #81b616;
  margin: 0;
}

:host.ng-valid.ng-touched .input:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(129, 182, 22, 0.5);
  margin: 0;
}
```

html

```
<input
  [(ngModel)]="value"
  class="input"
  (change)="onChange(inputRef.value)"
  [value]="value"
  #inputRef
/>
```

ts

```
import { ControlValueAccessor, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-custom-input',
  templateUrl: './custom-input.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./custom-input.component.css'],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      multi: true,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => CustomInputComponent)
    }
  ]
})
export class CustomInputComponent implements OnInit, ControlValueAccessor {
  constructor() {}

  public onChange: any = () => {};
  private _value = '';

  public onTouch: any = () => {};

  public get value() {
    return this._value;
  }

  public set value(v) {
    this._value = v;

    if (this.onChange) {
      this.onChange(this._value);
    }
  }

  ngOnInit() {}

  registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
    this.onChange = fn;
    this.onChange(this._value);
  }

  registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
    this.onTouch = fn;
    this.onTouch(this._value);
  }

  writeValue(value: any): void {
    this.value = value;
  }
}
```

`sign-in component` который использует custom-input
html

```
<div [formGroup]="loginForm">
  <app-custom-input id="mail" formControlName="username"></app-custom-input>

  <div class="margin">
    <app-custom-input id="password" formControlName="password">
    </app-custom-input>
  </div>
</div>
```

ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sing-in',
  templateUrl: './sing-in.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sing-in.component.css']
})
export class SingInComponent implements OnInit {

  public loginForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.loginForm = fb.group({
      username: fb.control('', [Validators.required, Validators.email]),
      password: fb.control('', [Validators.required]),
      persistent: fb.control(true)
    });
  }
  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте такие стили

```
.input {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid #c8cace;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: #000000;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  background: #fff;
  width: 50%;
}
:host.ng-invalid .input.ng-touched {
  border-color: #c61e1e;
  margin: 0;
}

:host.ng-invalid .input.ng-touched:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(198, 30, 35, 0.5);
  margin: 0;
}

:host.ng-valid .input.ng-touched {
  border-color: #81b616;
  margin: 0;
}

:host.ng-valid .input.ng-touched:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(129, 182, 22, 0.5);
  margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: Благодарю! сработало )